# Is it possible to nest `\cite[]` like `\cite[after \cite[foo]{bar}]{baz}`?

Tags: citing

After thinking about it a log time, I decided to use package `multibib` to have an extra bibliography for image sources. So for example the caption would contain `...\citeBQ{foo}...`.

This works fine until the image was painted after another source, like

`...\citeBQ{foo} after \cite[bla]{baz}...`.

Then I was wondering whether it wouldn't be more appropriate to use

`...\citeBQ[after \cite[bla]{baz}]{foo}...` instead, but that does not work.
The error message is something like

```
./part-1.tex:54: Use of \@citex doesn't match its definition.
\citeBQ ->\let \@citex \mb@@citex 
                                  \let \@newciteauxhandle \@auxoutBQ \csname...
```

Is this (ignoring any bad taste in citing) possible somehow (*somehow* meaning without re-inventing the world, i.e. in a rather simple way)?

**Attempt to provide an example**

(Please improve if you can)

```
%foo.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx}
\makeindex
\newcites{Q}{Bildquellen}
\begin{document}
\citeQ[after \cite[S.~16]{bar:2001}]{foo:2019}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{foo}
\bibliographystyleQ{alpha}
\bibliographyBQ{Q}
\end{document}
%% %in foo.bib:
%% @book{bar:2001,
%%  location = {Bonn},
%%  edition = {1},
%%  title = {Scans, {P}rints \& {P}roofs},
%%  rights = {© Galileo Press, Bonn 2001},
%%  isbn = {3-934358-89-6},
%%  series = {edition Page},
%%  abstract = {Beste Ergebnisse beim Scannen und Drucken},
%%  pagetotal = {372},
%%  publisher = {Galileo Press {GmbH}},
%%  author = {Helmut Kraus},
%%  date = {2001},
%%  year = {2001}
%% }
%% %in Q.bib:
%% @Unpublished{foo:2019,
%%   author = {Some One},
%%   title = {\textcopyright{} 2019},
%%   year = 2019,
%%   note = {Test},
%% }
```

Comment: Try `\citeBQ[{after \cite[bla]{baz}}]{foo}` (_i.e._, an additional pair of braces in the optional argument).

Comment: Doesn't change the error message, unfortunately. The result is that `baz` is cited correctly, but without `bla`, and `foo` is output literally like `[Bar01, after ]]foo`.

Comment: Then please show a compilable example